# Delete sub folders and files from a folder

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder with a bunch of user folders and files in it and need to delete out all of the contents but leave the folders showing all of their names.

The Folder Structure is:

```
D:\Users\aanderson\data\stuff
D:\Users\acarlson\data\stuff
D:\Users\banderson\data\stuff
```

and I want to delete everything but:

```
D:\Users\aanderson\ 
D:\Users\acarlson\ 
D:\Users\banderson\
```

I tried a couple different scripts but it pretty much just emptied the entire folder (Using test folders of course)

Answer (score 1):

From command line, the easiest way to do it is

```
for /d %a in ("d:\users\*") do (pushd "%~fa" && (rmdir . /s /q 2>nul & popd))
```

That is, for each of the subfolders, place a lock in it to avoid to it to be removed. In this case, the lock is the `pushd` as you can not remove the current working folder.

So, do the same in vbscript

```
Option Explicit

Dim shell, fso
    Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso   = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim folder
    For Each folder In fso.GetFolder("d:\users").SubFolders
        shell.CurrentDirectory = folder.Path
        On Error Resume Next : folder.Delete True : On Error Goto 0
    Next
```